# Get ID of linked clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this code in my fancybox script:

```
<a href="#" class="approve" id="178">yes</a>
```

When I try and use:

```
 var getid = $(this).attr('id');
 alert(getid);
```

I always get undefined. Can anyone please help?

Thankyou

Comment: you are using this for get your id but you need class name for get your id attribute of hyperLink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code

```
var getid = $('.approve').attr('id');
alert(getid);
```

Answer (score 3):

you are using `this` without any previous selection object that returns any selected DOM element, the possible way to get the id of the target element you want is yo use the `class` attribute on the target element

```
  var getid = $(".approve").attr('id');
   alert(getid);
```

or you can use the element's name which is `a` but it would select all the links in your html page

```
  var getid = $("a").attr('id');
  alert(getid);
```

or with any attribute of the element.

```
 var getid = $("a[href]").attr('id');
 alert(getid);
```

reference:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.approve', (function() {
    var getid = $(this).prop('id');
    alert(getid);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

use class name instead of this

```
var getid = $(".approve").attr('id');
 alert(getid);
```

or use tag name

```
var getid = $("a").attr('id');
 alert(getid);
```

or use attribute name

```
var getid = $("a[href]").attr('id');
 alert(getid);
```

if you want to refer the `<a>` tag using `this` like the following example

```
$("a").click(function(){             
    var getid = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(getid);
 });
```

jquery selector reference
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp